# Create an Eigen Matrix from a runtime C array with memory aligned

Tags: arrays, memory-alignment, eigen3

I have a runtime C++ array, which is indeed a matrix. I want to use Eigen3 to perform matrix computation(e.g., matrix multiplication, linear system solving) on it. It is well known that a convenient way is to use Eigen::Map. And it seems more efficient if the array is memory aligned.

Thus my question is, is it most efficient to first define the runtime C++ array with memory aligned(e.g., I can define an array with length n+32, then find the first address that is 32 aligned), then use Map wrapper? And is there more efficient way to perform matrix computation on the array based on Eigen3?

Thanks very much.

Comment: This depends on, e.g., your CPU (how efficient are unaligned memory accesses), your OS/C++ standard/compiler (how efficient can you allocate aligned memory), etc

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In fact, in my code, great amount of computation will be performed on the assigned memory. Thus the effort on allocate aligned memory seems negligible.